# Calculate new average from old average

Tags: javascript

I am building a rating system where the **maximum value is `5`** and the **minimum is `1`**.

I have the following rating information:

```
{
    timesRated: 2,
    worstRateSent: 1,
    bestRateSent: 5,
    overall: 3
}
```

Based on that, I know 2 persons rated this item. One of them rated `1`, the other one rated `5`, resulting an overall of `3`.

How can I keep calculating the overall when new ratings are input?

E.g. If a user rates this item as `3`. How to calculate the new overall?

```
{
    timesRated: 3, // Since a new rate was added
    worstRateSent: 1, // Keeps 1 since the rate sent was `3`
    bestRateSent: 5, // Keeps 5 since the rate sent was `3`
    overall: ?
}
```

Any help is appreciated :D

Comment: This question is not clear, "sent" what, by who to where?

Comment: Sorry @Liam, was expecting that that would be clear enough.

How can I increment the overall by giving a new rate?

Comment: @Liam, edited the question. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Well, you basically have to recalculate the total ratings by multiplying `overall * timesRated` then you would add the new rating to that number, increment `timesRated` by 1, and then divide the new total by the new number of times rated as your new overall.

Comment: @mhodges put it in an answer.

Comment: Also, two ratings one as a 1 and one as a 5 results in a 3, not a 2.5. `avg = sum(ratings) / total # of ratings`. Therefore, `6 / 2 = 3`

Comment: @mhodges 's solution will work, the problem is that if you do not have a collection of ratings, there will eventually be a loss of accuracy of the overall value

Comment: @mhodges, sorry. My bad on that

Comment: @Brian, exactly! I realized that "loss" during a few ratings. I was looking to a more accurate way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the way to do this would be to recalculate the total ratings by multiplying `overall * timesRated` then you would add the new rating to that number, increment `timesRated` by 1, and then divide the new total by the new number of times rated as your new `overall`.

As @Brian pointed out, you would have to deal with rounding errors, which can largely be accomplished with the use of `Math.ceil()` I can't guarantee this will be perfect, but it should definitely get you on the right track.

Let me know if you have any questions!

```js
var ratings = {
  timesRated: 0,
  worstRating: 0,
  bestRating: 0,
  overall: 0,
  addRating: function (newRating) {
    newRating = Number(newRating);
    if (!this.worstRating || newRating < this.worstRating) {
      this.worstRating = newRating;
    }
    if (!this.bestRating || newRating > this.bestRating) {
      this.bestRating = newRating;
    }
    var totalRatings = Math.ceil(this.overall*this.timesRated);
    totalRatings += newRating;
    this.timesRated++;
    this.overall = totalRatings / this.timesRated;
  }
};
$("button").on("click", function(){
  var newRating = $(this).attr("value");
  ratings.addRating(newRating);
  $("#timesRated").text(ratings.timesRated);
  $("#worstRating").text(ratings.worstRating);
  $("#bestRating").text(ratings.bestRating);
  $("#avgRating").text(ratings.overall.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Times Rated: <span id="timesRated"></span><br/>
  Worst Rating: <span id="worstRating"></span><br/>
  Best Rating: <span id="bestRating"></span><br/>
  Average Rating: <span id="avgRating"></span><br/>
</div>
<br/>
Add Rating: <button value="1">1</button> <button value="2">2</button> <button value="3">3</button> <button value="4">4</button> <button value="5">5</button>
```